# Exception in thread "main" scala.ScalaReflectionException

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark-sql

This is my code for joinning two dataframes

```
package org.test.rddjoins
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD


object rdd {

case class Score(name: String, score: Int)
case class Age(name: String, age: Int)

def main(args: Array[String]) {

val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName("rdd")
  .setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext._


val scores = sc.textFile("scores.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(s =>     Score(s(0), s(1).trim.toInt))
val ages = sc.textFile("ages.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(s => Age(s(0), s(1).trim.toInt))

scores.registerAsTable("scores")
ages.registerAsTable("ages")

val joined = sqlContext.sql("""
SELECT a.name, a.age, s.score
FROM ages a JOIN scores s
ON a.name = s.name""")
joined.collect().foreach(println)

}
}
```

I am getting the following error while running it:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.ScalaReflectionException: class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection in JavaMirror with primordial classloader with boot classpath [C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Compressed\eclipse\plugins\org.scala-lang.scala-library_2.11.8.v20160304-115712-1706a37eb8.jar;C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\Compressed\eclipse\plugins\org.scala-lang.scala-reflect_2.11.8.v20160304-115712-1706a37eb8.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\classes] not found.
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticClass(Mirrors.scala:123)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.staticClass(Mirrors.scala:22)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$typecreator1$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:115)
    at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe$lzycompute(TypeTags.scala:232)
    at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$WeakTypeTagImpl.tpe(TypeTags.scala:232)
    at scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$class.typeOf(TypeTags.scala:341)
    at scala.reflect.api.Universe.typeOf(Universe.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.attributesFor(ScalaReflection.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.attributesFor(ScalaReflection.scala:33)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.createSchemaRDD(SQLContext.scala:111)
    at org.test.rddjoins.rdd$.main(rdd.scala:27)
```

Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Apache Spark library missed in classpath.

Exception says that one of spark related class was not found to `classpath`.
You should modify your `classpath` to add specified jars.